# Sum of Dynamic Multi-Dimension array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I searched for few in-built methods and tried few logics from here and there but none can make me satisfied. I have created my own logic but is limited to a certain dimension of the array. I have managed to solve my problem for the project but as I said I am not satisfied.

Consider the array below:

```
 
$data = array
 (
    '0' => array
        (
            '0' => array
                (
                    'make_ready' => '',
                    'ready_time' => '0.55',
                    'rate' => '46',
                    'no_of_run' => '',
                    'fixed_cost' => '',
                    'variable_cost' => '25.3',
                    '0' => array(
                            'kg' => 2.66,
                            'rate' => 11.4,
                            'fixed_cost' => '',
                            'variable_cost' => 30.32,
                            '0' => array(
                                    'kg' => 2.66,
                                    'rate' => 11.4,
                                    'fixed_cost' => '',
                                    'variable_cost' => 30.32,
                                   ),
                        ),
                ),

        ),

    '1' => array
        (
            '0' => array
                (
                    'make_ready' => '1',
                    'ready_time' => '1.16',
                    'rate' => '36.47',
                    'no_of_run' => '',
                    'fixed_cost' => '36.47',
                    'variable_cost' => '42.31',
                ),

        ),

    '2' => array
        (
            'make_ready' => '2',
            'ready_time' => '0.29',
            'rate' => '360',
            'no_of_run' => '',
            'fixed_cost' => '720',
            'variable_cost' => '104.4',
        ),

    'size' => '1000 X 1200 X 1190',
    'up' => '3 X 4 / 17',
    'unit' => '4',
    'rate' => 16.32,
    'fixed_cost' => '',
    'variable_cost' => 65.28,
);
```

**Problem:**

I want to sum up all the values of array element where key is **'variable_cost'**, no matter how deep (in terms of dimension) is the array. Basically like a loop that can scan all the elements and do 'sum' if key matches.

I would like someone to help/suggest any logic where the calculations can be done till **nth** dimension.

For example like the movie *Inception*, in which they can go

> dream->with in a dream->to **nth** number of dream.

and come out with the sum of **'variable_cost'**. Hope you guys can understand the question here.

**Thank you.**

Comment: How are you generating this array? There is no uniformity anywhere in it which makes this problem harder for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a recursive function to sum all the variable_cost values:

```
function sum_variable_cost( $data, $total=0)  {
    foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            $total = sum_variable_cost($item, $total);
        } else if ($key=='variable_cost') {
            //echo $key . " " . $item . "\n";
            $total += $item;
        }
    }
    return $total;
}

echo sum_variable_cost( $data );
```

Basically it loops through the array and sees if there are other arrays and only adds values that contain the key `variable_cost`.

If you uncomment the echo line it will show this output:

```
variable_cost 25.3
variable_cost 30.32
variable_cost 30.32
variable_cost 42.31
variable_cost 104.4
variable_cost 65.28
297.93
```

Comment: thank you, that was so easy, I think I overlooked at the problem too much. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I had remove the tick (apologies), I found a bug in the logic, the final total is not the correct answer. For eg: 25.3 + 30.32 + 30.32 + 42.31 + 104.4 + 65.28 = 297.93. From the logic the final answer is incorrect. Thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer, it needed to be `$total = sum_variable_cost($item, $total);` .. feel free to re-add the tick.